# Proving two statements regarding combinatorics and numbers

Tags: discrete-mathematics

So i want to prove these two statements:

1) In a set of $n+1$ natural numbers, there exist  two numbers, that if we subtract on from the other, the result is dividable by $n$.

2) For every natural number n, there exists a number m, that is made of only $0$ and $5$, there is no other limitation on how many $0$ and $5$ it is made of.

Any help would be appreciated.
I came across it in discrete mathematics, so there is probably some combinatorics or something similar behind the proves, maybe even Dirichlet's principle.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Your second question is not clear, "for every n there is a natural number m", and then there is no relation between $n$ and $m$. Please make the correction. Also, for the first question, consider the possible set of remainders that the elements of the set can give upon division by $n$, and note that there are $n+1$ elements in the set, while only $n$ remainders $0,1, \ldots,n-1$ are possible upon division by $n$.

Comment: well i literally translated the qquestion from my mother language, there is nothing other than that stated. The relation is that n divides m, that is made of 0s and 5s. That's all there is. But it seems like i should construct a general algorithm or something, that gets a number m, dividable by n, and that's made of 5s and 0s. Probably that's how i could prove it, but i'm not sure how to start.

Comment: I have just checked your profile. I ,well, can make out a bit of Slovenian for you,if you like. There's no harm. Your question is more important than the language you speak. Somehow, I think I have understood the question as "for all $n$, there is a large $m$ consisting of only $0$s and $5$s such that $m$ is a multiple of $n$".

Comment: It's probably meant like that yeah. And yeah, i guess you could, but english isn't really a problem for me. Just a little rusty at first.

Comment: All right, so the answer of your question will be below in few minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your question is as spoken, then the answer is as follows.

First, the case of $n$ being odd.

To do this, we use the same principle as last time. Think about the numbers $5,55,555,5555,55555, \ldots$. Now, there are only $n-1$ possible remainders when you divide something by $n$, right? So suppose I take the following set: $5,55,555,\ldots,(55\ldots55)$, where $(55\ldots55)$ is the number which has $n+1$ fives. This set has $n+1$ elements.

By the first part of your question, there are two numbers in this set, say one with $k$ fives and one with $l$ fives, such that these leave the same remainder when dividing by $n$ (and $k > l$, say). Hence, their difference is a multiple of $n$. But then, when you take the difference of $55...55$ and $55...55$, then the number you will get will be like $55...5500...00$,right? (where there are $k-l$ fives and $l$ zeros). Hence, this number has only zeros and fives, and is a multiple of $n$.

Suppose that $n$ is even. We can write $n = m \times 2^k$, where $m$ is an odd number, and hence $k$ is the maximum possible power of $2$ that divides $n$. Then, since $10$ is a multiple of $2$, $10^k$ is a multiple of $2^k$. So what we do is the following:

1) Since $m$ is odd, find a number $555...555000..000$ which divides $m$.

2) Add $k$ zeros to $555...555000...000(000...000)$ (where $(000...000)$ is a new block of $k$ zeros), so that now this is also divisible by $2^k$.

This number, $555...555000...000(000...000)$ will be a multiple of $n$.

I'll give an example to illustrate.

Suppose $n=28$. Then $n = 2^2 \times 7$, so then $m=7$ and $k=2$.

For $m=7$, we consider the set $\{ 5,55,555,5555,55555,555555,5555555,55555555\}$. This set has $8$ elements, so two of them must leave the same remainder when divided by $7$. You can check that these two numbers are $5555555$ and $5$, because their difference is $555550$ ,and $5555550 = 7 \times 793650$.

Now, since $k=2$, just add two more zeros to $5555550$ to get $555555000$. This is a multiple of $28$, because $555555000 = 28 \times 19841250$.

This is the complete proof of the question.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the remainders when the $n+1$ integers are divided by n. Since there are only $n$ possible remainders, $0, 1, ... ,n-1$, at least two of the integers must have the same remainder. The difference of two integers with the same remainder is divisible by $n$.